# Verify User Watched YouTube Video in Backbone App

Tags: jquery-ui, backbone.js, youtube, marionette

I have a Backbone Marionette app with a Rails back-end. I need to be able to display a youtube video in a mobile browser on the Backbone side. Easy enough.

The place I'm running into trouble is figuring out how to validate that a user completely watched a video. Does anyone know how I can do this?

So far I'm letting the user view the video via [jquery_youtube](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/jquery_youtube/#Download) which more or less just wraps the youtube video in a modal window.

I'm not too familiar with the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#Playback_status) but it seems like `player.getPlayerState() = 0` might be what I'm looking for.

I was thinking that perhaps I could do

```
    events: 
      "beforeClose .ui-dialog-title": "checkVideoStatus"

    checkVideoStatus: (e) ->
      console.log e 
      console.log "log"
```

and then in the check video status I could verify that `player.getPlayerState() = 0` but I can't seem to get the log statements to fire which of course is because the dialog modal is outside of this view.

Any ideas for how I can verify that the user watched the video?

Comment: Couldn't you use one of Marionette's EventAggregator to pass messages between the modal and your view?

Comment: I could trigger something on the modal's beforeClose method. But I'm not really sure how to get a reference to the player itself to check the state and pass that along to my app...

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. You'd think the plugin would dispatch events to the parent document. Maybe it can't because of x-domain restrictions? It might be worth creating your own modal and using the [YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference) directly.

Comment: It's been a while but have a look at the [Popcorn.js](https://github.com/mozilla/popcorn-js) web video framework.